# vba countif for duplicates when validating another data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy data into new workbook and validate the data by removing duplicates keeping one cell value as the source.

All I wanted is the count of XD in the worksheet provided there are no duplicate Record locator.

Also I wanted the count to be in a msgbox. Can someone help ?

[image: ScreenShot of the Excel]

```
Sub openworkbook()

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\kjayachandiran\Desktop\ACUITY CF 1204-1210.xls")

Worksheets(2).Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\kjayachandiran\Desktop\New-Manjunath.xlsx")

Worksheets(1).Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Workbooks(3).Save
Workbooks(2).Close

ActiveWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets(1).Activate
Cells(1, 1).Select

Range("A366655").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(9), "=" & "XD")


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you edit your question another way? From this, I can't get what you want to have...
In this screenshot do you have the correct situation?

Comment: The output I want is the number is XDs in the column 9. But would like to make sure that a XD count is not a duplicate of the same record locator.

The output I want is the number is XDs in the column 9. But would like to make sure that a XD count is not a duplicate of the same record locator.

The column with record locator has duplicate PNRs hence have to ignore the duplicate out of them.

Say in excel terms. column9="XD" and column14="Non Duplicate PNR"

Comment: Do you want only output count of XDs? Do you need to do this multiple time or it one-time job?

Comment: @Gadziu its a one time job for a work book. I will execute the same code for other workbooks as well.